# Jenkins master node is rejecting connection with agent node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Everything was working fine until I rebooted Jenkins agent node and Master node. Since then I am seeing below issue

```
Nov 06 13:05:20 jenkinsserver01 jenkins[1040]: 2023-11-06 19:05:20.266+0000 [id=17035]        INFO        o.j.r.p.i.ConnectionHeadersFilterLayer#onRecv: [JNLP4-connect connection from 10.14.156.57:35998] Refusing headers from remote: LinuxSlaveNode-10.14.156.57 is already connected to this controller. Rejecting this connection.
```

I tried restarting service, rebooting the VM.
I am expecting agent is connected with Master without any issues

Comment: Jenkins is reporting that the node/slave/agent you are trying to connect is already connected to the server client. Try to restart the agent on Jenkins and retry the connection between jenkins and agent